# Ansible escaping a string issue on mac vs ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ansible

With the following code:

```
  - name: Add the gii config for main.php on staging
    blockinfile:
      dest: "{{ www_path }}/protected/config/main.php"
      marker: "//Gii"
      insertafter: "\'modules\'=>array\\("
      block: "{{ gii_content }}"
```

I'm getting a syntax error on OSX:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The offending line appears to be:

      marker: "//Gii"
      insertafter: "\'modules\'=>array\\("
                     ^ here
```

Yet on ubuntu, no such issue and the playbook runs seamlessly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you [run this through a YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=%0A%20%20-%20name%3A%20Add%20the%20gii%20config%20for%20main.php%20on%20staging%0A%20%20%20%20blockinfile%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dest%3A%20%22%7B%7B%20www_path%20%7D%7D%2Fprotected%2Fconfig%2Fmain.php%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20marker%3A%20%22%2F%2FGii%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20insertafter%3A%20%22%5C%27modules%5C%27%3D%3Earray%5C%5C(%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20block%3A%20%22%7B%7B%20gii_content%20%7D%7D%22%0A&type=json) it will tell you it discovered an unknown escape character, so OS X is right there. What is the purpose of `\'`? If the idea was to match that string and the backslash appears in the file like this, you should put two backslashes there:

```
  - name: Add the gii config for main.php on staging
    blockinfile:
      dest: "{{ www_path }}/protected/config/main.php"
      marker: "//Gii"
      insertafter: "\\'modules\\'=>array\\("
      block: "{{ gii_content }}"
```

If there are two backslashes right after `array` you would need to have 4 of them there, just for escaping. Though since `insertafter` takes a regular expression and `(` has a special meaning in regular expressions, it might be necessary to actually put 6 of them there.

```
  - name: Add the gii config for main.php on staging
    blockinfile:
      dest: "{{ www_path }}/protected/config/main.php"
      marker: "//Gii"
      insertafter: "\\'modules\\'=>array\\\\\\("
      block: "{{ gii_content }}"
```